# Chef - NoMethodError in Chef::Resource::Application

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, vagrant

I have a working Vagrant instance and now trying to use "application" cookbook with Chef/Vagrant, to be able to deploy from git and getting this error message:

```
FATAL: NoMethodError: undefined method `path' for
 Chef::Resource::Application
```

Naturally, "path" is an integral part of "application" recipe. if I comment it out, same message would be displayed for next attribute.

I've made sure that metadata.rb contains line:

```
depends 'application'
```

I've also reloaded vagrant instance to make sure all changes propagate and ran "berks update". In which direction I should search for the cause of this error?

Vagrantfile is pretty standard, and mostly consists of:

```
config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
    chef.json = {
      :mysql => {
        :server_root_password => 'rootpass',
        :server_debian_password => 'debpass',
        :server_repl_password => 'replpass'
      },
      :postgresql => {
        :password => {
          :postgres => "rootpass"
        }
      },
    }

    chef.run_list = [
      "recipe[iw-app::default]",
      "recipe[iw-app::db]",
      "recipe[iw-app::deploy]"
    ]
  end
```

While deploy recipe contains

```
user "#{node[:ii][:user]}" do
  system true
end

application node[:ii][:app_name] do
  path        node[:ii][:deploy_to]
  owner       node[:ii][:user]
  group       node[:ii][:group]
  repository  node[:ii][:repo][:url]
  revision    node[:ii][:repo][:branch]
  deploy_key  node[:ii][:repo][:deploy_key]
  packages    ["git"]
end
```

metadata.rb is just:

```
depends 'apt'
depends 'python'
depends 'application'
depends 'application_python'
depends 'postgresql'
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant part of your Vagrantfile?

Comment: Vagrant file is pretty standard, here is the main part:

config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
    chef.json = {
      :mysql => {
        :server_root_password => 'rootpass',
        :server_debian_password => 'debpass',
        :server_repl_password => 'replpass'
      },
      :postgresql => {
        :password => {
          :postgres => "rootpass"
        }
      },
    }

    chef.run_list = [
      "recipe[iw-app::default]",
      "recipe[iw-app::db]",
      "recipe[iw-app::deploy]"
    ]

Comment: Added more details to post description.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? It's okay to answer your own question. Please don't forget to mark an answer as correct! :)

Comment: +1 Seth. I'm getting the same error on `directory node['tomcat'] do
  rights :full_control, 'vagrant'
end`

Answer (score 1):

I was having a very similar issue.  In my case what solved it was to remove an incorrect variable that I was using inside the block that was throwing the exception.

For example the following was throwing:

```
ark "apachesolr-drupal" do
  url node['solri']['drupal']['url']
  version node['solr']['drupal']['version']
  path "/tmp"  
  action :put
end
```

with...

```
NoMethodError
-------------
No resource or method named `ark' for `Chef::Recipe "drupal"'
```

`node['solri']['drupal']['url']` is not set the following works:

```
ark "apachesolr-drupal" do
  url node['solr']['drupal']['url']
  version node['solr']['drupal']['version']
  path "/tmp"
  action :put
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like something pretty basic is wrong because the debugging process you have started, i.e commenting out the `path` command and basically getting the same error, doesn't make a lot of sense.

I would go through and check your assumptions about vagrant and your environment - do you have the correct cookbooks structure and dependencies in your cookbook directory, are you specifying the right attributes, are there any clues in the output of chef-solo?  I find that there's usually a subtle indication in the chef output as to what's going wrong.

Failing all that it's often useful to go over the source for the recipe that's failing.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a very similar issue. In my case what solved it was to remove an incorrect variable that I was using inside the block that was throwing the exception.

Check chef resource syntax!

```
git "#{node['customscripts']['dir']}" do
  repository node['customscripts']['url']
  reference node['customscripts']['ref']
  action :sync
  user root
  group root
end
```

Fix by add quotes to user and group:

```
git "#{node['customscripts']['dir']}" do
  ... 
  user "root"
  group "root"
end
```

Chef version is:

```
chef-client --version
Chef: 11.10.0
```